# Shift value when only CTRL key is pressed?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin, modifier-key

Create a VCL Forms application and in the main form's `OnMouseDown` event handler write:

```
procedure TForm2.FormMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  if Shift = [ssCtrl] then
    ShowMessage('CTRL pressed');
end;
```

Then run the app, press and hold the CTRL key down, with no other modifier keys, and then click on the form. No message is displayed. Why now?

So which value does `Shift` have in this case when only the CTRL key is pressed?

Comment: Why didn't you answer this yourself by evaluating `Shift` in the debugger?  It would have told you immediately that the contents of `Shift` are not just [ssCtrl] even when only one of the Ctrl keys is pressed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [`TShiftState`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TShiftState) type is defined like this:

```
type
  TShiftState = set of (ssShift, ssAlt, ssCtrl, ssLeft, ssRight, ssMiddle, ssDouble, 
    ssTouch, ssPen, ssCommand, ssHorizontal);
```

As you can see, is contains a lot more information than just the modifier key state.

When you hold down the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key and click on the form, `Shift` has this value: `[ssCtrl,ssLeft]`. That tells you that the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key is down, and the left mouse button is down. Note that this information is easy to obtain by using the debugger. Learning how to use the debugging to inspect the state of your program during execution is a very important skill.

If you wish to test for the state of the modifier keys, you need to mask out everything that is not a modifier key. Do that using the `*` operator, which is set intersection. This allows you to cut the information down to just the enumeration values of interest.

```
if Shift*[ssShift, ssAlt, ssCtrl] = [ssCtrl] then
  ....
```

Comment: Brilliant! The answer from Jerry Dodge is correct and good but this is more elegant.

Comment: Because `ssCtrl in Shift` is true when any combination of modifiers is down that includes the control key. But you specifically asked for only the control key.

Comment: Original question asks *"which value does Shift have in this case when only the CTRL key is pressed?*", it mentions nothing of any other modifier keys. Testing for ssctrl satisfies the original question.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz That's taking things very literally, but I think it is obvious enough that the asker did not realise that `Shift` reports about keys other than modifiers. Hence my edit to the question.

Comment: @David - Your edit to the question is quite fine. However an answer not taking into account *the obvious* is not necessarily wrong in my opinion.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz OK, that's fair.

Comment: @user1580348 `ssCtrl in Shift` only checks the state of the Ctrl key. if you hold down Shift or Alt along with Ctrl, `ssCtrl in Shift` will still be true even though the Shift/Alt key is down. If you want to make sure only Ctrl by itself is down, you have to take the states of the other keys into account.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz:  Your comment "Original question asks ..." reminds me a bit of answering the q "Would you like tea or coffee?" with "Yes." ;=)

Answer (score 5):

`TShiftState` is an enum set, meaning there could be more than one value. When you do `if Shift = [ssCtrl]` you are checking if it's *exactly* equal to that. But, there may be other values.

So instead, do this:

```
if ssCtrl in Shift then
  ...
```

Comment: This is also `True` when I hold both `Ctrl` and `Shift` modifier keys down. But the question was: "So which value does Shift have in this case when only the CTRL key is pressed?"

Comment: @user1580348 You already had it correct. The problem was how you were doing your check.

Comment: @user - It's ssCtrl of course. But in the question you state you click on the form, that's no more *only* the control key. Your question is inconsistent.

Comment: Of course when I ask "only the control key" everybody understands that I mean "only the control modifier key".